# Performance hit from blending large quad

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I have a game which runs pretty well (55-60fps) on a retina display.
I want to add a fullscreen overlay that blends with the existing scene. However, even when using a small texture, the performance hit is huge. Is there an optimization I can perform to make this useable?

If I use a 80x120 texture (the texture is rendered on the fly, which is why it's not square), I get 25-30FPS. If I make the texture smaller, performance increases, but quality is not acceptable. In general, though, the quality of the overlay is not very important (it's just lighting).

Renderer utilization is at 99%.

Even if I use a square texture from a file (.png), performance is bad.

This is how I create the texture:

```
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

    // Create default framebuffer object.
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &lightFramebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, lightFramebuffer);

    // Create color render buffer and allocate backing store.
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &lightRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, lightRenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA8_OES, LIGHT_WIDTH, LIGHT_HEIGHT);

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, lightRenderbuffer);

    glGenTextures(1, &lightImage);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, lightImage);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, LIGHT_WIDTH, LIGHT_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, lightImage, 0);
```

And here is the rendering...

```
/* Draw scene... */

glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);


//Switch to offscreen texture buffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, lightFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, lightRenderbuffer);
glViewport(0, 0, LIGHT_WIDTH, LIGHT_HEIGHT);

glClearColor(ambientLight, ambientLight, ambientLight, ambientLight);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

/* Draw lights to texture... */

//Switch back to main frame buffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
glViewport(0, 0, framebufferWidth, framebufferHeight);  

glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glview.lightImage);    

/* Set up drawing... */

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Here are some benchmarks I took when trying to narrow down the problem. 'No blend' means I glDisable(GL_BLEND) before I draw the quad. 'No buffer switching' means I don't switch back and forth from the offscreen buffer before drawing.

```
(Tests using a static 256x256 .png)
No blend, No buffer switching: 52FPS
Yes blend, No buffer switching: 29FPS //disabled the glClear, which would artificially speed up the rendering
No blend, Yes buffer switching: 29FPS
Yes blend, Yes buffer switching: 27FPS

Yes buffer switching, No drawing: 46FPS
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Instead of blending the whole lightmap afterward, I ended up writing a shader to do the work on the fly. Each fragment samples and blends from the lightmap (kind of like multitexturing). At first, the performance gain was minimal, but then I used a lowp sampler2d for the light map, and then I got around 45FPS.

Here's the fragment shader:

```
lowp vec4 texColor = texture2D(tex, texCoordsVarying);
lowp vec4 lightColor = texture2D(lightMap, worldPosVarying);
lightColor.rgb *= lightColor.a;
lightColor.a = 1.0;

gl_FragColor = texColor * color * lightColor;
```

Comment: I suspect the `glView` buffer switches are probably the culprit here. What's going on in those methods? Why not use `glBindRenderBuffer`?

Comment: I'll inline those methods for clarification.

Comment: Ok to debuf the perf issue, try pre-rendering the overlay (just leave it static for now), and then copying that into main buffer every frame. That will at least tell you if the buffer switches are slow (ie doing two calls to glBindFrame, glBindRender, glViewport every frame).

Comment: If I do everything but the drawing (including the BindRender, Viewport stuff and actually drawing the lights), it's fast. So I think it has to be the final drawing/compositing that's slow.

Comment: And if you do `glDisable(GL_BLEND)` does it speed up?

Comment: Sorry, I think you're right. I did some more testing and it does seem like buffer switching has an impact. Any ideas for how to mitigate that?

(Tests using a static 256x256 .png)
No blend, No buffer switching: 52FPS
Yes blend, No buffer switching: 46FPS
No blend, Yes buffer switching: 29FPS
Yes blend, Yes buffer switching: 27FPS

Yes buffer switching, No drawing: 46FPS

Comment: Oh wait, I left the glClear line in,  which seemed to artificially speed up the "Yes blend, Yes buffer switching" benchmark. It runs at 29FPS without the glClear. I'll update the question. So, it does seem like the main problem is just drawing a large blended quad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I think you've run up against the limitations of the hardware. Blending a screen-sized quad over the whole scene is probably a particularly bad case for the tile-based hardware.
The PowerVR SGX (on the iPhone) is optimized for hidden surface removal, to avoid drawing things when not needed. It has low memory bandwidth because it's optimized for low power device.

So screen-sized blended quad is reading then writing every fragment on the screen. Ouch!

The `glClear` speed up is related - because you're telling GL you don't care about the contents of the backbuffer before rendering, which saves loading the previous contents into memory.

There's a very good overview of the iOS hardware here: http://www.imgtec.com/factsheets/SDK/POWERVR%20SGX.OpenGL%20ES%202.0%20Application%20Development%20Recommendations.1.1f.External.pdf

As for an actual solution - I would try directly rendering your overlay on the game scene.

For example, your render loop should look like:

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

// Set up game view port and render the game
InitGameViewPort();
GameRender();

// Change camera to 2d/orthographic, turn off depth write and compare
InitOverlayViewPort()

// Render overlay into same buffer 
OverlayRender()
```

Comment: Thanks. Yea, I kind of came to the same conclusion. Unfortunately, I can't use your solution-- the overlay I'm drawing is really more of a lightmap, so it affects the actual game environment pixels. I ended up writing a shader to do the same work, with pretty good success. I'll post the details of that in my question. Thanks for all your help investigating this!

Comment: Awesome - I'd love to see what you did.

Comment: I'm using screen-sized quad blended over the whole scene on my game, and didn't get a drop in frame-rate (30 fps in 3G, 60s in retinas). The slowdown could be in the creation of the texture ? are you doing it every frame ?

Answer (score 1):

If you render to a render target on a PowerVR chip, switch to another render target and render, then switch back to any previous render target you will suffer a major performance hit. This kind of access pattern is labelled a "Logical Buffer Load" by the OpenGL ES Analyzer built into the latest Instruments.

If you switch your rendering order so that you draw your lightmap render target first, then render your scene to the main framebuffer, then do your fullscreen blend of the lightmap render target texture your performance should be much higher.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm, on iPad 1 using iOS 4.2, enable/disable GL_BLEND for one full screen quad toggled between 18 and 31 fps. In both runs, renderer utilization was 90-100%.

Answer (score 0):

Even before fiddling with the texture, make sure your shader is optimized. When filling a 960x640 screen (614400 pixels) any operation in the fragment shader has a huge impact.

One good thing to create a specific version of your fragment shader for this situation. It should be something like this:

```
varying mediump vec2 vertexTexCoord;
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, vertexTexCoord);
}
```

Create another program with this fragment shader and use it before drawing your big quad, then restore the normal program. The iPhone 4 is able to render about 7 full-screen, 1:1 textured quads per frame with blending, but it quickly drops to about 1 with a more sophisticated shader.

(Additionally in your case, try to render your overlay texture first, then the normal elements, then the texture over the rest. It should improve performance by a significant margin.)